# KeyStore Signing with Different Fingerprint

Tags: java, android

I am having a weird issue when signing and uploading an Android app.

We received this JKS file. And when I run:
`keytool -list -v -keystore key.jks -storepass THE_PASSWORD -keypass THE_PASSWORD`

To list all the information about it, I get the following:

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: 1
Creation date: 12 Feb 2016
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=..., OU=..., O=..., C=ZA
Issuer: CN=..., OU=..., O=..., C=ZA
Serial number: ********
Valid from: Sun Apr 28 17:21:31 SAST 2013 until: Thu Apr 29 17:21:31 SAST 2038
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  D5:A5:CF:***
     SHA1: 55:18:5F:***
     SHA256: DC:36:CF:***
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  codeSigning
]
```

However, when using Android Studio, I try to generate a signed APK and use this JKS file, the build and apk gets produced, except with a different key?

When I run:

```
keytool -list -printcert -jarfile app-release.apk
```

I get the following output:

```
Owner: CN=..., OU=..., O=..., C=ZA
Issuer: CN=..., OU=..., O=..., C=ZA
Serial number: ********
Valid from: Sun Apr 28 17:21:31 SAST 2013 until: Thu Apr 29 17:21:31 SAST 2038
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  EC:FB:D6:***
         SHA1: 40:A3:F0:***
         SHA256: 40:41:3C:***
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  codeSigning
]
```

Notice all information is the same... the serial number, owner, issuer, everything except the fingerprints.

I am not signing it in debug mode, my Gradle files are pointing to the correct JKS file.

Also for testing purposes I have tried a different JKS file. And viewed the JKS file compared to the APK and all information is correct. Including the SHA1 key.

Is there anything that I can try or anything small that I must be missing?
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after what feels like forever I have finally solved the issue.

The keystore used was a file that was originally converted from a .p12 file. Even though that new keystore file contained the correct fingerprints and correct format, there is a bug in Android Studio where it doesn't sign it with the correct fingerprints if the .p12 file was not converted correctly or Android Studio doesn't pass the correct values when signing the APK with this keystore file.

You will need to sign the APK manually. And this is kind of a mission to do. So I have made an automated script that will do it for you.

https://github.com/SierraII/morphthis

This script will sign APK files with the specified keystore file. The APK file will be signed whether it has been previously signed or not.

Anyone who runs into this issue, I hope this saves you 3 days!